# C# Net CF - how to take a picture without interaction?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, camera

Is there a possibility to take a picture using phone's camera without user interaction?
I'd like to write a short app that only takes sequence of pictures and the user should be able to set number of pictures, location, quality and time between shots. After starting the app should take pictures without further interaction. This program should for examlple take a sequence of 250 pictures of moving clouds so I could make a ten second movie from those pics.

Greeting
and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great resource [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx). You could also use DirectShow, but it's more complex.

Comment: Thx for quick and valuable response ;)